# Webstorm karma/jasmine angularjs testing - reference error module is undefined

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, webstorm

I'm trying to set up WebStorm to develop AngularJS. I've followed the [instructions from JetBrains](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2013/10/running-javascript-tests-with-karma-in-webstorm-7/) and I'm trying to run the test from [that tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02).

```
describe('PhoneCat controllers', function() {
  beforeEach(module('phonecatApp'));

  describe('PhoneListCtrl', function(){

    it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', inject(function($controller) {
      var scope = {},
          ctrl = $controller('PhoneListCtrl', { $scope: scope });

      expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(3);
    }));
  });
});
```

I'm getting the following error

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 7.0.3\plugins\js-karma\js_reporter\karma-intellij\lib\intellijRunner.js" --karmaPackageDir=C:\Users\L\node_modules\karma --serverPort=9876 --urlRoot=/
Testing started at 21:02 ...

    ReferenceError: module is not defined
        at null.<anonymous> (C:/Users/L/WebstormProjects/AngularJS/test/unit/ControllerTests.js:4:16)
        at C:/Users/L/WebstormProjects/AngularJS/test/unit/ControllerTests.js:3:1


Process finished with exit code 0
```

My directory layout is

- test/unit/ControllerTest.js
- test/karma.conf.js

**karma.conf.js** below

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Sun Feb 16 2014 20:49:06 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      {pattern: '*.js', included: true},
      {pattern: 'unit/*.js', included: true}
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit', 'growl', 'coverage'
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera (has to be installed with `npm install karma-opera-launcher`)
    // - Safari (only Mac; has to be installed with `npm install karma-safari-launcher`)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows; has to be installed with `npm install karma-ie-launcher`)
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
    captureTimeout: 60000,


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

angular-mocks.js is missing
See http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/452824?tstart=0

Answer (score 2):

in karma.conf.js should change to :

```
basePath: './',

$files: [
      {pattern: './*.js', included: true},
      {pattern: './unit/*.js', included: true}
    ],
```